# How can I solve this problem "Failed to compile "

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Row, Col, List } from 'antd'
import Axios from 'axios'
import { useState } from 'react'
import SideVideo from './Sections/SideVideo'
import Subscribe from './Sections/Subscribe'



function VideoDetailPage(props) {

    const videoId = props.match.params.videoId
    const variable = { videoId: videoId }

    const [VideoState, setVideoState] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.post('/api/video/getVideoDetail', variable)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data.success) {
                    setVideoState(response.data.videoDetail)

                } else {
                    alert('fail')
                }
            })
    }, [])

    if (VideoState.writer) {
        return (
            <Row gutter={[16, 16]}>
                <Col lg={18} xs={24}>
                    <div style={{ width: '100%', padding: '3rem 4rem' }}>
                        <video style={{ width: '100%' }} src={`http://localhost:5000/${VideoState.filePath}`} controls />

                        <List.Item
                            //이 부분은 비디오 좋아요 부분
                            actions={[<Subscribe userTo={VideoState.writer._id} />]}
                        //따로 component 만들어서 페이지 보여주게 함.
                        //따로 만든 component에 사용자 id를 props로 넘겨주기 위해 userTo={Video.writer._id} 이렇게 사용
                        >
                            <List.Item.Meta
                                // avatar ={VideoState.writer.image}

                                title={VideoState.title}
                                description={VideoState.description}
                            />

                        </List.Item>

                        {/* Comment */}

                    </div>
                </Col>
                <Col lg={6} xs={24}>
                    <SideVideo />
                </Col>
            </Row>
        )
    } else {
        <div>...loading</div>
    }

    
}

export default VideoDetailPage
```

This is my code that has a problem when I use `if(VideoState.writer)`:

```
Failed to compile
./src/components/views/VideoDetailPage/VideoDetailPage.js
  Line 63:9:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

I don't how I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `<div>...loading</div>` expression that isn't actually used for anything. Not returned, not assigned to anything, nothing. You probably meant to return it, i.e. `return <div>...loading</div>;`

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! I got solved this problem!